# Server and client side, Java

Tags: java, client-server

I try to make client sending some data to the server. In some reason it's always enter exception region...

I just want server accepting the data. And after that it needs to do this simple function.

The initialize of the socket, reader and writer is ok.

Client side code:

```
public void SendPlayer(String Name, float Score,int place) throws NullPointerException
{
    out.println("New High Score");
    try
    {
        while (!in.readLine().equals("ACK"));
        out.println(Name);
        out.println(Score);
        out.println(place);
    }
    catch (IOException e)
    {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Server side code:

```
while(true)
{           
    try
    {
        if (in.ready())
        {
            option = in.readLine();
            while(option == null)
            {
                option = in.readLine();
            }
            switch(option)
            {
                case ("New High Score"):
                {
                    out.println("ACK");
                    System.out.println("ack has been sent");
                    this.setHighScore(in.readLine(),Integer.parseInt(in.readLine()),
                    Integer.parseInt(in.readLine()));
                    break;
                }
                default:
                {
                    System.out.println("nothing");
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
    } 
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        System.out.println("Exception e");
    }
}
```

Comment: Please share full exception

Comment: Why your `while (!in.readLine().equals("ACK"));` contain `;` ?

Comment: The while is until I dont get ack...The full exception is NullPointerException on the line of if(in.ready)

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that you cannot compare null with a String.
The best is that you surround with try and catch the function call.

```
try {
    SendPlayer (/*Here the params*/);
    //Continue, since no null pointer exception has been thrown
} catch (NullPointerException) {
    //Your handling code here...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As per your comment - *The full exception is `NullPointerException` on the line of `if(in.ready)`*

Its clear from Exception that variable `in` is not initialized. Please check it again.

---

A best practice to avoid `NullPoinerException` while comparing `String` is compare in reverse order as shown below:

```
while (!"ACK".equals(in.readLine()));
```

---

Still there is one more issue in your code.

Client sending three values to server as shown below:

```
out.println(Name); // String
out.println(Score);// float
out.println(place); // int
```

Now at server side your are converting `float` to `int` using `Integer.parseInt(in.readLine())` as shown below that will result in `NumberFormatException`

```
this.setHighScore(in.readLine(),Integer.parseInt(in.readLine()),
Integer.parseInt(in.readLine()));// converting Score to int
```

---

For example

```
Integer.parseInt("2.0");
```

will result into

```
java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "2.0"
```

---

One more sample code

```
float val = 2;
String str = String.valueOf(val);
Integer.parseInt(str);
```

will result into

```
java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "2.0"
```